# Does making std::initializer_list const change anything?

Tags: c++11

```
std::initializer_list<int> FOO = {1, 2, 3};
const std::initializer_list<int> BAR = {1, 2, 3};
```

What are the differences between those two variables?  From my understanding of `std::initializer_list`, access is `const`-only anyway.  Does making the entire thing `const` actually change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `std::initializer_list` has a generated `operator =`. So the second declaration prevents

```
BAR = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [every member function of `std::initializer_list` is qualified as `const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), I cannot think of any practical situation where this would make a difference.

If you were directly playing with its type *(e.g. using `std::is_same` or `std::is_const`)* then the `const` would matter.